# Use custom table in log analytics query

Tags: azure, log-analytics-workspace, azure-monitor, kusto

Is it possible to create & reference a custom table in a Kusto query over a Log Analytics Workspace?

Specifically, I'd like to create tables to help provide metadata for my alerts.  i.e. Rather than using scheduled alerts (having to maintain various alerts and various scoped queries to account for each system's maintenance window) I'd like to define one table where I state the resource ID and the start/stop times for each maintenance window (potentially having multiple rows for the same resource; e.g. to cover different schedules for weekends vs week days).  I can then use this table to say which machines should be online at a given time, and thus only alert on "no recent heartbeat for resource" for those resources which are expected to be online at a given time.

I've found details on [consuming logs from log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/logs/manage-logs-tables?tabs=azure-portal) on a computer to create such a custom table, but that's not what I'm after.  I want to create a table to hold non-log data.  I suspect I could abuse the custom log tables for this purpose; but I'm wondering if there's a more correct approach?

I've seen that I can [query resource graph tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/logs/azure-monitor-data-explorer-proxy#query-data-in-azure-resource-graph-preview), so it's possible to approach this using the resource's tags; but that doesn't offer the flexibility that I'm after / that a dedicated table could give.

```
let nowtime = toint(format_datetime(now(),'HHmmss'));
let heartbeats = 
    Heartbeat
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(10m)
    | distinct _ResourceId;
arg("").resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
  and tags['inScopeForMonitor'] =~ 'true'
| project id
, startTime = toint(replace_string(tags['startTime'],':',''))
, stopTime = toint(replace_string(tags['stopTime'],':','')) 
, x = nowtime
| where (startTime < stopTime and startTime <= nowtime and stopTime > nowtime)
  or (startTime > stopTime and (startTime <= nowtime or stopTime > nowtime))
| where id !in~ (heartbeats)
```